is there any array reverse indexing in c like python's a[-1]?
I'm working on my school assignment and have to print an array's elements in reverse order.
is there any shortcut to do it or I shall do it all by myself?
If it were to be python I would just type a[-1:] and it would work, does c also have something like this?

You have to do it all by yourself. No such shortcut in C Standard Library. BTW, instead of looping 0, 1, ... n - 1 you can loop backwards n - 1, ..., 1, 0. Remember array indexes in C go from 0 to n - 1.

As an aside, in Python you’d type a[::-1] to reverse a list. In C, just iterate backwards.

In C you don't know length of the array when it decays, so how can C know where the end is to do reverse indexing? For languages where the length it's obviously trivial: Which programming language first used negative indexing to mean counting from the end?


print an array's elements in reverse order.

This easiest is
int a[N];
//  Assign array elements with TBD code.

for (size_t i = N; i-- > 0; ) {
  printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}

// or 
size_t i = N;
while (i > 0) {
  i--;
  printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}



To explicitly use negative indexes:
int a[N];
//  Assign array elements with TBD code.

int *p = a + N - 1;
for (int i = 0; i > -N; i--) {
  printf("%d\n", p[i]);
}

// or

int *p = a + N;
for (int i = -1; i >= -N; i--) {
  printf("%d\n", p[i]);
}


Good, but I'd suggest int *p = a + N and int i = -1; i >= -N so the last element is p[-1], not p[0],

@Kevin Added your idea.

No, there is no such support. You should do it explicitly.
When C was created, a[-1] didn't have the meaning of "last element". Did Python invent this?
In fact, a[-1] is "an element which is 1 before the pointer a". This meaning is sometimes useful in C, but not for arrays.

Python isn't the first language to do that: Which programming language first used negative indexing to mean counting from the end?

There's no support of negative indexing in C. However, C preprocessor allows us to add it (kinda). Although it's not pretty, it works:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEFINE_INDEX_FUNCTION_FOR(type)\
    type type##_index(type *array, size_t length, long long index) {\
        if (index < 0) return array[length + index];\
        return array[index];\
    }

DEFINE_INDEX_FUNCTION_FOR(int)
// now `int_index` function is defined and we can use it
// if we wanted to use char instead, we could do
// DEFINE_INDEX_FUNCTION_FOR(char)
// which would define `char_index`

int main() {
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    size_t length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);

    printf("%d\n", int_index(array, length, -2)); // -> 4
    printf("%d\n", int_index(array, length, -1)); // -> 5
    printf("%d\n", int_index(array, length, 0)); // -> 1
    printf("%d\n", int_index(array, length, 1)); // -> 2
    printf("%d\n", int_index(array, length, 2)); // -> 3
}

